How to containerize a Blazor .NET 8 app using auto RenderMode and therefore has 2 projects with Docker?
I'm trying to containerize a Blazor app knowing that I have the Server project and the Client project.
I wanted to know if I should right click on the Server project and create a Dockerfile for just the server project knowing that Blazor is basically a 2 projects in 1 kind of project or does the Client project also needs its own Dockerfile (and therefore they maybe need to be ran with Docker Compose to be able to communicate) ?

The server serves up the client you only need to publish the server project.

Got it ! so a single dockerfile on the server would do then, thank you so much !
